# Getting a vector of dictionary values in an array, python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, sparse-matrix

I am trying to get a vector of specific dictionary values which are in a numpy array.  Here is what the array looks like:

```
import numpy as np
edge_array = np.array(
    [[1001, 7005, {'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.35, 'type': '99', 'modes': 'cw'}],
     [1001, 8259, {'lanes': 10, 'length': 0.46, 'type': '99', 'modes': 'cw'}],
     [1001, 14007, {'lanes': 7, 'length': 0.49, 'type': '99', 'modes': 'cw'}]])
```

I have a vector for the first two values of each row (i.e. `1001` and `7005`, but I need another vector for the values associated with `'lanes'`.

Here is my code so far:

```
row_idx = edge_array[:, 0]
col_idx = edge_array[:, 1]
lane_values = edge_array[:, 2['lanes']]
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
lane_values = edge_array[:, 2['lanes']]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Please let me know if you need any further clarification, thanks!

Comment: Note that the `dtype` of this array is `object`.  `edge_array[:,2]` is functionally the same as a list of dictionaries.  So you have to use a list operations (map, comprehension) to operate on the individual dictionaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subexpression `2['lanes']` does not make sense: you are indexing into the number 2.

Instead, try:

```
[rec['lanes'] for rec in edge_array[:, 2]]
```

Or:

```
import operator
map(operator.itemgetter('lanes'), edge_array[:,2])
```

The above will give you a regular Python `list`; if you want a NumPy array you'll have to call `np.array()` on the list.

But the better solution here is to transform your data into a "structured array" which has named columns and then you can index efficiently by name.  If your array has many rows, this will have a big impact on efficiency.

Comment: I get the following error when I try that:  `lane_values = edge_array[:, 2]['lanes']
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: @AndrewEarl: Now that you've updated your question with the exact input data, I've updated my answer with an exact solution.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks.  I'll look into making a structured array as I have many, many, many rows.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a fully working example. Hard to work with that. The types are unclear. I suspect, that you work with numpy somehow, but well, hard to tell.

In all means, the indexing with 2['something'] is incorrect and the error tells you why. It is tried to index with a key in an integer. Look up how indexing is done in python / numpy.

But this is how you **could** extract your 'lanes':

```
map(lambda x: x['lanes'], edge_array[:, 2]))
# OR (if you want a vector/np-array)
vec_of_lanes = np.array(map(lambda x: x['lanes'], edge_array[:, 2])))
```

More in numpy-style:

```
vec_of_lanes = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x[2]['lanes'], 1, edge_array)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, will try that now.  How would you suggest creating a fully working example?  Is it because the `edge_array` does not work in your code?

Comment: The problem was, that you just showed us the printed output, so it's not valid python syntax as commas are omitted. It was also unclear if you index lists or numpy arrays.

Comment: Ok, I am working with a numpy array and have edited that.  Sorry for being an amateur but, once I've implemented: `map(lambda x: x['lanes'], edge_array[:, 2]))` how do I create a vector out of the values of `lanes` ?

Comment: I think you should read more docs as you are missing basic stuff! I will edit the answer.

Comment: Excellent! Yours works like a charm too.  Thanks.  I'll definitely read up on my basics a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

@Zwinck suggested a structured array.  Here's one way of doing that

Define a dtype for the dictionary part.  It has fields with different dtypes

```
dt1 = np.dtype([('lanes',int), ('length',float), ('type','S2'),('modes','S2')])
```

Embed that dtype in a larger one.  I used a sub-array format for the first 2 values:

```
dt = np.dtype([('f0',int,(2,)), ('f1',dt1)])
```

Now create the array.  I edited your expression to fit `dt`.  The mix of tuples and lists is important.  I could have transferred the data from your object array instead (todo?)

```
edge_array1 = np.array(  
    [([1001, 7005], ( 9,  0.35, '99','cw')),
     ([1001, 8259], ( 10, 0.46, '99','cw')),
     ([1001, 14007], (7,  0.49, '99', 'cw'))], dtype=dt)
```

Now the 2 int values can be accessed by the 'f0' field name:

```
In [513]: edge_array1['f0']
Out[513]: 
array([[ 1001,  7005],
       [ 1001,  8259],
       [ 1001, 14007]])
```

while 'lanes' are accessed by a double application of field name indexing (since they are a field within the field):

```
In [514]: edge_array1['f1']['lanes']
Out[514]: array([ 9, 10,  7])
```