# Add data to 3d array from genfromtxt

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to generate a 3d NumPy array with the structure [[string, [ID, (int,int,string, string, string)]]].  I use a dictionary now for this data that looks like target[chr][ID]=(a,b,c,d,e,f).  I cannot figure out how to get the data from the genfromtxt object into the array.  This is what I have done.

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt(self.target_bed_file, delimiter='\t', usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), dtype=None)
print(data[0])
#(b'chr1', 3004040, 3005439, 1, b'L1_Rod', b'LINE', b'L1')
target_array = numpy.zeros([21, len(data)], dtype=None)
target_array = target_array.reshape(target_array.shape+(1,))
print(target_array.shape)
#(21, 425372, 1)
target_array[data[0:,0],data[3:,1],:]=(data[1:,2])
```

I have tried a few variations of that last line but I always get "IndexError: too many indices for array."

Edit:  Based on hpaulj answer I have done this

```
dt1 = numpy.dtype([('start', int), ('stop', int), ('family', 'S10'), ('type', 'S10'), ('class', 'S10')])
dt = numpy.dtype([('chr', 'S3'), ('ID', int), ('f1', dt1)])
data = numpy.genfromtxt(self.target_bed_file, delimiter='\t', usecols=(0,3,1,2,4,5,6), dtype=dt)
print(data[0]
#(b'chr', 1, (3004040, 3005439, b'L1_Rod', b'LINE', b'L1'))
target_array = numpy.zeros([len(data), 21, 1], dtype=object)
target_array[data['chr'], data['ID'][3:]] = data['f1'][1:]
```

Now I get "IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type."  I am finding 3d arrays difficult to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `shape` and `dtype` of `data`.  It is not a 2d array.

```
data[0]
```

produces `(b'chr1', 3004040, 3005439, 1, b'L1_Rod', b'LINE', b'L1')` a structured array record, not a row of a 2d array.

You access 'columns' of such an array by name, e.g. `['f0']`.

So your assignment expression should be:

```
target_array[data['f0'],data['f1'][3:] = data['f2'][1:]
```

Although that will give dimensional errors.  For one field you are using all the rows of `data`, another is all but 3, another all but 1.  They should all index the same number of rows.

On a minor point, you don't need to reshape `target_array` - just include the extra `1` in the initial definition:

```
target_array = numpy.zeros([21, len(data),1], dtype=float)
```

What's the purpose of that last `1` dimension?  What's the purpose of the `21` dimension?

`dtype=None` is the same as `dtype=float`.  Where you wanting `dtype=object`?

You mention wanting an array with structure:

```
[[string, [ID, (int,int,string, string, string)]]]
```

Do you have in mind a real structured array, with a compound `dtype`, or an object array with do-it-yourself objects in each slot.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37228678/901925 - an example of a complex compound dtype.

Comment: I had this data structured as a dictionary.  While that works, I am using larger files now and want to move to arrays.  The last dimension is a tuple with the data that is associated with a chromosome and ID.  I made edits based on the link you provided but get a new error now.  Wrapping my head around 3d arrays is proving more difficult than I had anticipated.  I think I want a structured array but I am not 100% on that.

Comment: What are the 3 dimensions of your array supposed to represent?  An array is indexed with integers, row and column numbers, not strings. `data['chr']`` contains strings.  You may want a `pandas` table instead.

Comment: I am trying to break the dictionary mindset.  I was thinking of making each row a chromosome (21 rows); each chromosome has some unknown number of ID's (columns); each ID has a collection of data.  That is how I structured the dict.  For numpy might it be better for each row to represent an ID with the columns then representing the data?  I can build that as an object array.  I cannot make a structured array because I have mixed dtypes?

Comment: If you map the `chr` field onto numbers (21?), then I think you can put your data in a 2d array with `dtype=dt1`.  `rows` would the 21 chromosomes, `columns` the large number of `ID`, and the data in each cell.